# How to distribute react to Nginx (centos 7 version)

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

**The Setup**
I have setup a FrontEnd environment using create-react-app. I set it up for deployment with Nginx.
The first main screen is loaded properly.

**Environment**

- React Version 8.1.2
- Node Version 16.13.2
- Nginx Version 1.24.0
- Express Version 4.18.2

**The Problem**
It worked properly when running with npm start. The ssl has also been applied properly.
I also set nginx.
However, when running with node server.js, security is not applied to the pop-up screen,
and the screen does not come out.
when I loaded the screen with window.popup(), it was loaded indefinitely.
And window.location.href function is the same phenomenon.(But, I can go to the main.)
The page except Main will not be refreshed.

**What I've Tried**

FrontEnd

1. I have set the path.

BackEnd

1. I have checked my CORS policies to but they seem fine

**Code**

server.js (front)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCCow.png)

Window.popup()

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q2tk.png)

NginX Setting

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
       location / {
         root [build file path];
         index index.html index.htm;
         try_files $url $url/ /index.html;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your browser's console here?